# Using re.VERBOSE flag with str.replace in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, str-replace

So I like to split regex strings on to multiple lines for management purposes. This can be done by using `flags=re.VERBOSE` with `str.extract` something like this:

Create df:

```
d = {'col1':['test&&', 'testing..', 'testing!!'], 'col2':['testing','testing','testing']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

```
reg = r"""
(&&)|
(\.\.)|
(!!)         
"""

t = df['col1'].str.extract(reg, flags=re.VERBOSE)
df['col1'] = t[0].fillna(t[1]).fillna(t[2])
df['col1']
```

output

```
0    &&
1    ..
2    !!
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Can the same thing be done when using `str.replace` as it does not seem to be working for me.

```
reg = r"""
(&&)|
(\.\.)|
(!!)         
"""
t = df['col1'].str.replace(reg, "", regex=True, flags=re.VERBOSE)
t
df['col1'] = t[0].fillna(t[1]).fillna(t[2])
```

error:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fillna'`

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with `flags` or `re.VERBOSE`. Those parts worked perfectly fine. It's the part *after* that, where you do `df['col1'] = t[0].fillna(t[1]).fillna(t[2])`, that causes the problems.

Comment: Hint: What object are you calling `.fillna()` on? What type do you expect that object to be? What type *is* that object?

Comment: Were you expecting your `replace` call to do exactly the same thing as your `extract` call? The `df['col1'] = t[0].fillna(t[1]).fillna(t[2])` line only makes sense with the `extract` output. The `replace` code does something completely different.

Comment: haha, I see it now! replace returns a single column. Not sure why I did not check that! thanks